# ASP.NET IIS StreamWriter WinIOError

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm trying to have my website execute code when some action is preformed (doesn't matter for this question). A button press would suffice.

The code that fails to execute is this:

```
foreach (Dictionary<string, string> d in entryList)
{
    foreach (KeyValuePair<string, string> k in d)
    {
        csv.Append(SanitizeValue(k.Value));
        csv.Append(delimitor);
    }
    csv.Append('\n');
}

using (System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath))
{
    file.WriteLine(csv);
    file.Flush();
    file.Close();
}

            return true;
```

The error I receive is this:

> at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
>   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32
>   bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess
>   access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String
>   msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
>   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding
>   encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost) at
>   System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding
>   encoding, Int32 bufferSize) at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String
>   path) at
>   InventoryImportExportLibrary.InventoryLocatorCSVWriter.Write(List`1
>   entryList) in
>   c:\InventoryLocator\InventoryImportLibrary\InventoryLocatorCSVWriter.cs:line
>   65 at InventoryImportExportLibrary.InventoryEntryBuilder.SaveToFile()
>   in
>   c:\InventoryLocator\InventoryImportLibrary\InventoryImportExportLibrary.cs:line
>   50 at
>   InventoryLocatorWebApplication._Default.buttonTestImport_Click(Object
>   sender, EventArgs e) in
>   c:\InventoryLocator\InventoryLocatorWebApplication\Default.aspx.cs:line
>   163

The error is here: using `(System.IO.StreamWriter file = new System.IO.StreamWriter(filePath))`

The code I've show works when run by a generic console program. So my thinking is that this issue is rooted in the ASP.NET process or has something to do with permissions.

Why might this not be working? Is it a permissions issue? How might I fix this?

Comment: You haven't shown us the error message, only the stack trace.

Comment: IIS  run as Network Service by default. Network Service  has only user privileges, which means it may not have the privileges to read/write file from/to that path

Comment: [System.UnauthorizedAccessException] = {"Access to the path 'C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\File.txt' is denied."}